# SQL Query to Mongo DB to get the sum with group by

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Im a beginner to no SQL databases how can I convert the following the SQL query to Mongodb Query?

```
select e.empno,sum(f.points)
from employee e, assignment a, finalreport f 
where e.empno = a.empno  and a.assid = f.assid
group by e.empno
```

I want to get the total points given to employees who have been assigned an assignment. There are three tables employee, assignment, and finalreport. The points are in the final report table.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: thank you, how can I convert with JOIN to MongoDB?

Comment: That's step 2, which unfortunately is outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Second tip of today: the debate between the implicit (what you wrote) and explicit join syntax is a never-ending one, have fun reading the tons of explanations about the pros and cons of both. I use the implicit one when possible, because it makes more obvious and easier to read which tables are involved. BUT, I don't want to start another debate here about this. My tip is: don't accept this kind of tips blindly. Read about it, try using both and have your own preference, which in the end is the only right approach.

Comment: thank you very much for the tip, yes I will definitely do more checking and testing and it to my knowlegde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of different ways, i'll show the simplest approach using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which is the Mongo equivalent of sql `join` ( or rather a "left outer join").

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "assignment",
      "localField": "empno",
      "foreignField": "empno",
      "as": "assignments"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "finalreport",
      "localField": "assignments.assid",
      "foreignField": "assid",
      "as": "reports"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      points: {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: "$reports",
            in: "$$this.points"
          }
        }
      },
      empno: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dwvr-qfv5kN)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked like a charm, is there any source that I can use to learn how to write these type of queries because the official documentation doesn't seem to give this much in depth info

Comment: I personally am not aware of any such source, there are some blog posts which show toy example of certain use cases that you can use. The best way in my opinion is just trial and error.

Comment: thank you for the advice. one small issue tho. My points output becomes always "0" when  my "reports" field has more than 1 object. Say the "reports" field gives the output for 1 employee like [aasid:"Assignment1", points:15], [assid:"Assignment2", points:20]. how can I get the total points in this scenario, because the "points" field will get an array of points like points:[15],[20].

Comment: can you show a playground example? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: my bad, its working well, I had redundant attributes in two of my tables so it didn't give me the total. thank you very much